# Animate CSS tooltip (:after selector)

Tags: css, animation, tooltip

I'm implementing a tooltip for a website I'm working on and I found [this solution](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/) but I can't figure out a way to animate it.

What I'm trying to do is slide down the tooltip.

The code is below. Any help is appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" title="This is some information for our tooltip." class="tooltip">
  <span title="More">CSS3 Tooltip</span>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.tooltip{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}

.tooltip:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS attribute: animation. Make everything have absolute positioning, then use the animation attribute to animate the tooltip.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_animations